# Preencher ComboBox sem repetições

Tags: c#, combobox

Estou tentando preencher um `ComboBox` a partir de um `db`, mas o `ComboBox` é preenchido com muitos itens repetidos!

```
OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbCombo;

Con.Open();
OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT NomeInv FROM tbFev;
Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Cmm.Connection = Con;
OleDbDataReader DR;
DR = Cmm.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(DR);

DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "", "NomeInv", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
comboBox1.DataSource = dv;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NomeInv";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "";

Con.Close();
```

Deste modo está vindo todas as informações do campo `NomeInv`, inclusive repetidos.

Há algum código pra evitar isso ?

Comment: Coloquei como uma resposta Maurício, para ficar no local correto e como atendida sua dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um `DISTINCT` no seu `SELECT`.

Desta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NomeInv FROM tbFev;
```

Todos as linhas completamente idênticas serão juntadas pela expressão "distinct".